# WordPress Export table as csv using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i'm trying to export my plugin table in the same page. i tried to do hidden iframe but it still does not work

**PHP:**

```
add_action( "wp_ajax_export_plugin", "export_plugin" );   //update_records is action
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_export_plugin", "export_plugin" );

function export_plugin(){
  global $wpdb;
   $wpdb->show_errors = TRUE;
   $wpdb->suppress_errors = FALSE;

  

      
      $plugin_name = $_POST['plugin-name']; // PLUGIN NAME
      $plugin_export_type = $_POST['export-type']; // PLUGIN EXPORT TYPE as CVS/SQL/XML
  
      $plugin_name; // ?? not defined in original code
      $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_myplugin`",ARRAY_A);
    
    
    
      $csv_output = '"'.implode('";"',array_keys($results[0])).'";'."\n";;
    
      foreach ($results as $row) {
        $csv_output .= '"'.implode('";"',$row).'";'."\n";
      }
      $csv_output .= "\n";
    
      $filename = $plugin_name."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
      header("Content-type: application/force-download");
      header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . $plugin_export_type);
      header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$plugin_name.$plugin_export_type);
      header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

      echo $filename;
      exit;


}
```

**AJAX JQUERY:**

```
success:function(data){
            
     $('#ifram_download').src="/app?download=1&filename=" + data + '.csv';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of echoing the filename, echo the file contents.

```
<?php
echo $csv_output;
exit;
```

An alternative is to not use Ajax. Simply navigate to the Ajax URL via a link

```
<a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>?action=myexport">Export</a>
```

As the file is force downloaded the the url of the browser will remain the same.

Comment: it's just include the file contents, but how can i put them inside file to download it?

Comment: The `header("Content-type: application/force-download");` should result in a download..

Comment: Thank you so much sir it's working, but if i want to pass data with like it should be like this? `<a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>?action=myexport&plugin-name=meow">Export</a>` ?

Comment: Re passing data, yes, just use the URL (GET) variables. You can read these in your PHP script with `$plugin = get_query_var( 'plugin-name')` or `$plugin = $_GET['plugin-name']`